# How to fix FFFF-FFF partition

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, partition, filevault

[image: Screenshot of GPT]

I wanted to create a dualboot setup on my Macbook Pro so that I could run Big Sur along with High Sierra. Hence, I created another partition of size 37 GB (disk0s3) to install Big Sur on that partition. However, after installing Big Sur, I can no longer access the content of the partition that used to have High Sierra (disk0s2). The drive doesn’t show up on the boot menu. When I ran diskutil from Terminal, it shows unknown partition. How can I recover my data from that partition? I had FileVault enabled on that partition.

As suggested by Jean_JD, I ran the following commands using terminal and found the following outcome from diskutil as presented in the screenshot below:
[image]

Do I need to run additional commands to verify the disk or the partition is accessible right away?

Comment: I suggest erasing the whole disk, reinstall High Sierra and recover data from backup. Also a 128GB disk is too small to go messing about with multiple operating systems - so if you want Big Sur install it on an external disk.  And there are other questions and answers about FFFF... partitions.

Comment: Do you remember if the High Sierra partition was a apfs or hfs structure?

Comment: @Gilby:  Unfortunately, I don’t have backup of the files inside the partition containing High Sierra which is why I need to go through these tedious process. Is there a way to rescue the data from that partition?

Comment: @Jean_JD: High Sierra partition was APFS structure

Answer (score 0):

You can try from the terminal in Recovery Mode, modify the ffff partition by apfs structure.
The command are :

`diskutil umountDisk disk0`

then

`gpt remove -i 2 disk0`

then

`diskutil umountDisk disk0`

then

`gpt add -i 2 -b 409640 -s 164063192 -t 7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC disk0`

then you give the result of

`diskutil list`

Comment: I ran all the commands and found the following outcome from diskutil list

Answer (score 0):

[image]

@Jean_JD
I ran all the commands and found this outcome from diskutil list.

Comment: Perfect. Can you try boot on High Sierra? You reboot the system pushing the alt key and "Macintosh HD" should be proposed.

Comment: @Jean_JD : Yes. Now I can boot into High Sierra. Thanks you so much.

Comment: That's right. :)